Build a custom query with some exceptions from two access tables
I'd like to ask for your assistance regarding a requirement that I want to achieve.I'm not exactly sure on how to approach this query.
I have two tables in Access Table A & Table B.
Table A schema



Employee_Supervise_Name_A
Employee_A_ID
Employee_Supervised_Name_B
Employee_B_ID




joe
1234
Steve
5612


Martine
7777
Elena
2222


Smith

Bob
2222


Michael
5555
alexa



Ana

Edgar
6666


Lili
1010
Alonso
2020


Hans

Carlos




Table B schema



Employee_ID
Employee_Code




1234
A


5612
B


7777
C


5555
D


6666
E


2222
F


9999
H



Expected result
Based on the commun employee_id, I want to map the employee_code
Notes: It is also possible that the employee_id of table A does not exist in table B or that the field is empty. For this kind of scenario, I simply want to return the row with empty fields.



Employee_Supervise_Name_A
Employee_A_ID
Employee_Code_A
Employee_Supervised_Name_B
Employee_B_ID
Employee_Code_B




joe
1234
A
Steve
5612
B


Martine
7777
C
Elena
2222
F


Smith


Bob
9999
H


Michael
5555
D
Alexa




Ana


Edgar
6666
E


Lili
1010

Alonso
2020



Hans


Carlos






Are you sure the expected result is correct? Shouldn't the Employee_B_ID for Smith be 2222?

Maybe I don’t understand your requirement, but do you realize you can left join the same table twice? You gotta give it an alias like left join Table_B as SuperviserB on SuperviserB.Employee_ID = Table_A.Employee_A_ID then you do the other one left join Table_B as UnderlingB on UnderlingB.Employee_ID = Table_A.Employee_B_ID.

In Access query design, pull in Table_B twice. Access will assign the second instance an alias name like Table_B_1. Join one to Employee_A_ID and other to Employee_B_ID.

ID's of employees are commonly considered as primary keys when it comes to creating table (as they are unique identifiers). In your case you have two employee tables who have their own primary keys conjoined together without a super key which in my opinion is a bad schema design.
But here it is anyway:-
    select tt.Employee_supervise_name,tt.Employee_a_id, tt.employee_code_a, tt.Employee_Supervised_Name_B, tt.Employee_b_id, B.Employee_code as employee_code_b 
    from (select A.Employee_supervise_name, A.Employee_a_id, B.employee_code as employee_code_a, A.Employee_Supervised_Name_B, A.Employee_b_id
   from 
    A left join B on A.Employee_a_id = B.Employee_id) as tt 
    left join B on tt.Employee_b_id = B.Employee_id ;

